# 3rd party pixel without error or delays

Tags: javascript, tracking

I have a database of 3rd party tracking pixels that I add to my own output to either inform that third party of an event or let them set their cookie. Easiest to handle are image pixels - you just set up `<img src="...">` and everything just works. However, some pixels in database are of `script` type - i.e. 3rd party server returns empty string and `Content-Type` as `text/javascript`.

So far I thought of following approaches:

1. Just insert them in same `img`. Request will succeed, but there will be warning on console and some users just don't like that
2. Give those pixels proper `<script>` tag while writing it with `document.write` - depending on browser, slow response of 3rd party server might cause entire page to halt, and that is also very bad.
3. Dynamically generate DOM `script` element with necessary `src` and append it somewhere in `head`. Seems to work, but I didn't test extensively yet and not sure if there's any hidden problems I'm missing.

So, is there some generally accepted method to include such pixels in a way that would guarantee no errors in console or halts on slow 3rd party server response? (additional points if it can handle some other arbitrary content type, not just `text/javascript`).

Answer (score 1):

There's an async attribute which IE ignores, yet makes your scripts load asynchronously in other browsers, thereby not blocking site download.

http://davidwalsh.name/html5-async

On how to insert it well (and perhaps that also works in IE, look at comments):
https://plus.google.com/116910304844117268718/posts/TripyAFKMof